How can I get scholarships to study a Master in Europe?
I'm an undergraduate student from Chile in Mathematics and it's my last year. I was thinking about applying for a Masters somewhere in Europe. I tried investigating on the scholarships that Chile has with other countries, sadly most of the Universities that had something in Pure Mathematics only had the scholarship for PhD or DPhil. I don't know anything about this kind of things and asking over here is, perhaps, a good start to expand my knowledge over this.
I'm not searching for an option or something like that. I only want to know how hard is to have a scholarship, or how the scholarships environment works.

It would be better if you ask in your own environment and Profs, specially if they have connections outside of Chile.

Not that "somewhere in Europe" isn’t a uniform place. Even though there are some European funding programs, many scholarships are organised on a national or even smaller scale. Describing the scholarships for each and every European country isn’t exactly well-focused, either.

I don't know how it works in Chile, but many countries' education ministries and universities' international departments keep a record of scholarships that their students can apply for. For instance, you can find the South African DHET calendar for scholarships here.
From the link above, there are upcoming scholarships in Ireland, the UK, and Erasmus.
There are plenty of other scholarships out there. To find one, I would suggest finding out whether your university subscribes to idox or a similar service to streamline funding calls. I would also suggest reaching out to your university's international department, if you have one, or even your education ministry, to see if they can help.
International scholarships, particularly in Europe, tend to be incredibly competitive, so be prepared to put a lot of work into your application. For many of them, particularly for research-orientated programmes, it helps if you already have a contact such as a supervisor in the country or at the university you'd like to study at. Try reaching out to a few academics who's work interests you to see if they are aware of any funding opportunities.
Best of luck!

Thank you for your answer. I will try searching more about it over here and put the best of mine to get one of that programmes.

Well, in some countries the MS is totally free, you just need to fee a small semester fee. But there are so many websites that can help you to find MS program scholarships worldwide, and you can apply correct filters to find ones in Europe or elsewhere. I did the same during my time and it actually worked.

www.findamasters.com
www.mastersportal.com
www.masterstudies.com
www.master-and-more.eu
www.mastersavenue.com

Good Luck!

Please don't encourage shopping questions by posting lists of links

okay, is this why you downvoted my answer?

you can't tell who downvoted. Its anonymous.

@Sursula what if the OP is not very tech savvy and good at Googling. How should we answer such questions?

@NaveedAhmed You shouldn't answer them at all. Such questions are off-topic.

@NaveedAhmed I would suggest to the OP that maybe academia is not the best path for an individual having trouble googling things.

I will try with the links, thanks.
I'm sorry if the question seems like a shopping question, I was trying to find more information of how this works.
